# Should EFCore migrations be committed to version control?

Tags: c#, git, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Running `dotnet ef migrations add XYZ` will result in [a Migrations directory being created](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#create-your-first-migration) in the project. Should this directory be committed to version control (Git, etc)?

Comment: Yes Of course, if you are using EF Core as Code First Solution, you should definitely save it in your source control

Comment: @AliKianoor is there a reason for saving it? ie, what does it do?

Comment: The files can be used to change database versions. If you made a migration to add a new table, the same migration can be used to go back and delete this table.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, you should commit EFCore migrations to version control. 
 When a data model change is introduced, EF Core compares the current model against a snapshot of the old model to determine the differences, and generates migration source files; the files can be tracked in your project's source control like any other source file. 
**Lets assume** you're not committing your migrations to version control. And after some time you or one of your team mates make a change to data model then, EFCore will fail to get last snapshot and hence updating database may cause some conflicts/changes which may already exist..!

Answer (score 2):

You can always recreate migrations yourself using `dotnet ef migrations add <name>` but that only works for simple operations.
If you have complex migrations with custom SQL, or DDL commands that need to run in a specific order then you need to keep the migrations file in VCS to preserve that order.

An example would be creating a computed column. You need to create the table with the first migration, then create another with handwritten SQL to create the SQL function in the second, then a third one migration to introduce the computed column that uses that function.
All these operations need to follow an order an cannot be created with a simple `dotnet ef migrations ...` command

Comment: Noting and making it clearer: it is not a choice under those circumstances. It is a MUST.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely the migrations should be committed in source control.

Deleting migrations will make it impossible for EF to generate future migrations for future changes to an existing database.

Also, if you did the following...

1. Add a migration
2. Execute the migration, creating a new table
3. Then delete the generated migration code
4. Add a new migration with the same table name
5. Execute again the migrations

Here EF will fail since the underlying table already exists and the migration created from #4 will be a 'create' statement instead of an update statement.

Comment: Yes and no. Deleting the migrations won't have an immediate effect, as adding new migrations is solely based on the **snapshot** file. However, you won't be able to roll back changes (`dotnet ef migrations remove --force`) since the migrations `Down()` method will be called on rollback/removing an migration to bring the database on its previous state. Also without the migration files you can't do automatic migrations via `context.Database.MigrateAsync()` since the migration classes won't be compiled into the binary